How to combine rows from different sheets into one sheet?
I have 5 excel sheets, sharing same number of rows and columns.
I would like to make one sheet by combining rows from these 5 sheets in a way that each row from these sheets come below to each other. How is this possible in Excel / R / or any other programming language.
I have shared my sample input and desired output..
Input data:
SHEET 1:



Year
A
B




2000
0.2
0.3


2001
0.5
0.4


2002
0.1
0.2


2003
0.2
0.3


2004
0.5
0.1


2005
0.2
0.2



SHEET 2:



Year
st1
st2




2000
blue
blue


2001
red
red


2002
yellow
yellow


2003
green
green


2004
white
white


2005
black
black



Desired output



Year
x1
x2




2000
0.2
0.3


2000
blue
blue


2001
0.5
0.4


2001
red
red


2002
0.1
0.2


2002
yellow
yellow


2003
0.2
0.3


2003
green
green


2004
0.5
0.1


2004
white
white


2005
0.2
0.2


2005
black
black



I would appreciate any help in this regard.
Thank you in advance.

Here is an R response. Essentially:

lapply() over sheet names, reading each sheet into a list.
Skip the header row and assign the same column names so we can bind them into one data frame by name.
Set col_types = "text" for the columns we are going to bind, so there is no issue with combining character and numeric vectors.
Add row number to each data frame.
Bind into one data frame.
Sort this data frame by row number to achieve desired output.
Remove row number.

library(dplyr)
lapply(
    readxl::excel_sheets(file_path),
    \(sheet)
    readxl::read_excel(
        file_path,
        sheet = sheet,
        skip = 1,
        col_names = c("year", "x1", "x2"),
        col_types = c("numeric", "text", "text")
    ) |>
        mutate(rn = row_number())
) |>
    bind_rows() |>
    arrange(rn) |>
    select(-rn)

# # A tibble: 12 × 3
#     year x1     x2
#    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
#  1  2000 0.2    0.3
#  2  2000 blue   blue
#  3  2001 0.5    0.4
#  4  2001 red    red
#  5  2002 0.1    0.2
#  6  2002 yellow yellow
#  7  2003 0.2    0.3
#  8  2003 green  green
#  9  2004 0.5    0.1
# 10  2004 white  white
# 11  2005 0.2    0.2
# 12  2005 black  black 

Frame challenge: join rather than combine columns
This is kind of awkward and it feels wrong to combine character and numeric vectors. It would be more natural to join them:
lapply(
    readxl::excel_sheets(file_path),
    \(sheet)
    readxl::read_excel(file_path, sheet = sheet)
) |>
    Reduce(
        \(x, y) full_join(x, y, by = "Year"),
        x = _
    )

#    Year     A     B st1    st2   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
# 1  2000   0.2   0.3 blue   blue  
# 2  2001   0.5   0.4 red    red   
# 3  2002   0.1   0.2 yellow yellow
# 4  2003   0.2   0.3 green  green 
# 5  2004   0.5   0.1 white  white 
# 6  2005   0.2   0.2 black  black 

This is better - our numbers are numeric and our text is character. Using Reduce() over the list means this approach will generalise to any number of sheets.

In fact, my actual data is all numeric.. But, I just put the sample data here to help understand the output I required..

@tom great - you can skip the col_types() bit in the first method then

Since in the OP its written using any programming language, whether Excel/R/Other hence posting it an answer using Excel Formulas


=VSTACK({"Year","x1","x2"},SORT(VSTACK(Table_One,Table_Two)))


NOTE:

The above formula works with the MS365 in current channel.
Highly suggested to convert the range of data in sheets into Structured References aka Tables and then use the above formula.
This can also be accomplished using Power Query as well.



Thank you very much .. But would it be possible in MS2021?

Here is an R function that merges sheets with common time column, either read in using openxlsx::read.xlsx or read.csv. Depending on the setting you can produce different output formats.
Additionally, if it happens you have identical names in the separate sheets, so mergeing gets tricky, we can provide new names to rename them.
> rd_merge <- \(r, new_names, tcol=1, long=FALSE) {
+   yr <- el(lapply(r, names))[tcol]
+   ncv <- el(lapply(r, ncol)) - 1L
+   if (!missing(new_names)) {
+     r <- Map(setNames, r, 
+              Map('c', yr, lapply(new_names, paste, 
+                                  if (ncv > 1) seq_len(ncv) else '', sep=''))
+     )
+   }
+   if (long) {
+     r <- Map(`[<-`, r, '.id', value=seq_along(r))
+   } else {
+     stopifnot(Reduce(identical, sapply(r, names)[1, ]))
+   }
+   Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), x=r)
+ }

Usage
Excel data as shown in OP
> rd_ex <- Map(openxlsx::read.xlsx, 'foo.xlsx', sheet=1:2)  ## recommended
> rd_merge(rd_ex)
  Year   A   B    st1    st2
1 2000 0.2 0.3   blue   blue
2 2001 0.5 0.4    red    red
3 2002 0.1 0.2 yellow yellow
4 2003 0.2 0.3  green  green
5 2004 0.5 0.1  white  white
6 2005 0.2 0.2  black  black
> rd_merge(rd_ex, new_names=c('foo', 'bar'))  ## same, but using new names
  Year foo1 foo2   bar1   bar2
1 2000  0.2  0.3   blue   blue
2 2001  0.5  0.4    red    red
3 2002  0.1  0.2 yellow yellow
4 2003  0.2  0.3  green  green
5 2004  0.5  0.1  white  white
6 2005  0.2  0.2  black  black
> rd_merge(rd_ex, long=TRUE, new_names='x')  ## desired (?) long format
   Year     x1     x2 .id
1  2000    0.2    0.3   1
2  2000   blue   blue   2
3  2001    0.5    0.4   1
4  2001    red    red   2
5  2002    0.1    0.2   1
6  2002 yellow yellow   2
7  2003    0.2    0.3   1
8  2003  green  green   2
9  2004    0.5    0.1   1
10 2004  white  white   2
11 2005    0.2    0.2   1
12 2005  black  black   2

Here an example with sheets that have identical names,
> rd_ex <- Map(openxlsx::read.xlsx, 'foo2.xlsx', sheet=1:2)
> lapply(rd_ex, names)
$`foo2.xlsx`
[1] "Year" "st1" 

$<NA>
[1] "Year" "st1" 

that we can't merge that easily. But with the function we can provide new names.
> rd_merge(rd_ex, new_names=c('foo', 'bar'))
  Year foo    bar
1 2000 0.2   blue
2 2001 0.5    red
3 2002 0.1 yellow
4 2003 0.2  green
5 2004 0.5  white
6 2005 0.2  black

We can do the same with your read in .csv files.
> rd_csv <- lapply(c('foo21.csv', 'foo21.csv'), read.csv)
> lapply(rd_csv, names)
[[1]]
[1] "Year" "st1" 

[[2]]
[1] "Year" "st1" 
> rd_merge(rd_csv, new_names=c('temperature', 'ppt'))
  Year temperature    ppt
1 2000         0.2   blue
2 2001         0.5    red
3 2002         0.1 yellow
4 2003         0.2  green
5 2004         0.5  white
6 2005         0.2  black


Thank you for this detailed answer. This function works well. But, I am encountering a problem.  I have all numeric data (precipitation data) on 12 sheets (calendar months name).. Problem is that , this function reads all sheets and arrange the rows according to the ascending order instead of following the sheets sequence. I want to merge the rows according to the sequence of sheets ..PLease guide me how to overcome this problem. Thank you

@tom Does Map(openxlsx::read.xlsx, 'foo2.xlsx', sheet=1:12) |> do.call(what='rbind') work? Column names should be identical throughout the sheets.

I was following this one " rd_merge(rd_ex, long=TRUE, new_names='x')  "  . This was according to my requirements

I tried , it is not working

@tom And what is wrong with the code in my comment above?

It is binding the sheets below each other . I want to bind the rows below each other from each sheet. .the solution you provided first was good.. but the problem was that it was binding the rows according to the ascending order instead of the sequence of sheets.

@tom Using merge will sort the data, this is why I thought you need this rbind solution. I'm not sure about the difference of "binding the sheets below each other" and "binding the rows below each other from each sheet"?

Thank you very much for your constant help and guidance on this matter..
